# Correctly display modal screen in Angular 7

Tags: asp.net, typescript, angular7, router

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.0 project with Angular 7 material.

I've correctly implemented the `forgot password` function within Angular which when invoked, would prompt a user to enter in their email address. This would send them a password reset email link. Once that link is clicked, they are redirected to Angular's page which is where my problem lye. What I'm hoping to achieve is redirect the user to a modal screen instead of a page.

> .NET

```
       [HttpGet("reset")]
        public IActionResult Reset(string email, string token)
        {
            if (token == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (token != null)
            {
                //sends them to angular application with email and token
                return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/resetPassword" + $"?email={email}&token={token}");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

This is what the link from the server side would look like => 
localhost:4200/reset?emailaddress=samsmith@gmail.com?token=fdsajfdfadsafdasfdsafdsafdasfdsaf
```

What I've tried so far is to specify the `outlet` as modal within the route, which didn't work.

`{ path: 'reset', outlet: 'modal', component: ResetComponent }`

To summarize:
User clicks on `Forget password` => then request goes to server side, generating a token => token and user email is sent back to Angular modal screen => user enters password and confirms password.

How should I go about it?

Comment: Your problem is really unclear. Can you post your code ? 

Instead of adding reset to your route path, just make the button send an HTTP call, 
this will not redirect, and you open a modal screen when the server respond.

Comment: How does that work? From the time the user clicks on the link within their email, they would be directed to a new page.

Comment: think the reset would need to be routed to a page then a `Modal` opened in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @SWilko how would that look like? Could you show me an example?